# Ошибка при обновлении 1С-Битрикс (php 7>8) MySQL Query Error

Tags: php, mysql, битрикс, phpmyadmin, cms

С чем может быть связана следующая ошибка, и каким образом она решается. Текст ошибки, появляется на странице обновления CMS, а также модулей (при попытке загрузки и установки обновления).

```
MySQL Query Error: delete o1 FROM b_user_access_check o1, b_user_access_check o2 WHERE o1.id > o2.id AND o1.USER_ID = o2.USER_ID AND o1.PROVIDER_ID = o2.PROVIDER_ID [[1205] Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction]
MySQL Query Error!
```